# How to read only the folders

Tags: php

I have this code that reads all the content of a folder and converts it to an array, but I want to only the code reads folders and no files.

For example in language file are these files and folders:

```
../
en_EN/
fr_FR/
happy.rar
```

And the code is:

```
$folder = '../language/';
$return  = scandir($folder, 1);
$return = array_diff($return, array('.', '..','error_log','_notes'));
$return = str_replace(".php", "", $return);
```

I can make exceptions in the 3rd line, but I want to create an exception for all the files.

Is there a way to make that?

Thank you

Comment: `$return` is array i think.isn't it? this line itself raise error:- `$return = str_replace(".php", "", $return);`

Comment: You can iterate over $return and use `is_dir()`.

Comment: why you are not using [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to select only folders simply as per below with `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag.

and use `basename()` to get only folder name.

```
$a = glob("../language/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR ); // $a has only folders
foreach($a as $file){
    echo(basename($file));
}
```